# Hide OptionSet Value of Ribbon Button ( Status Reason of Disqualify Button )

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-365, crm-ribbon-workbench

I want to hide some `optionset` values from `Disqualify` button; actually these are `statusreason` of disqualify `state`.
I can do this with any `field` on the form with simple `JS`.
But for a button in ribbon( like Disqualify Button ), I do now know how to do this.
I googled, but did not found any similar issue.
issue is this :
I have some option set values in disqualify button of lead(which are `statusreason` of disqualify `state`) that are not necessary any more.
I can not delete them, because my history and report will destroy.
So I need to hide them, But the disqualify button is in ribbon and I do not know how to access that.
Note that I am aware how to work with ribbon workbench; if it is necessary to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I followd [this](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/240705/remove-status-reason-options-from-lead-disqualify-ribbon-flyout/663279) thread and find a way.

@Andrew Butenko answer's solves the problem.
In his youtube video, he shows how to do this.
According to the video, in the first function he writes; he uses `xml` to populate the `flayout`. But you can do this via `ribbonworkbench` visual tools and add your buttons to `flayout` menu section. there is no need to write the first function.
But to do this you must set your command to each button you add.
Also somebody replied my question in this [thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/484232/hide-optionset-value-of-ribbon-button-disqualify-button) in the microsoft community; But I did not try that. The solution is similar to what I said.
But actually I changed my way.
I write a `WorkFlow` that in it's condition I check the `satusreason` and It's trigger is on `statusreason`.
When the record goes to that special `statusreason`, I stop the workflow with status of canceled with a message that : This status is not valid anymore.